# Jquery Unobtrusive Validation not firing in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

As the title says, I am having issues with JQuery Unobtrusive validation in javascript in an MVC application.

What I have done:

Inputs on my form have been bound with appropriate rules which will be checked in my custom javascript:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="rates_taxes" id="rates_taxes" data-val='true' data-val-ispositive="You must enter a positive value here or 0" data-val-isnumeric="You must enter a numerical value here. (e.g 250000)" required>

    ...
    jQuery.validator.addMethod('isnumeric', function (value) {
        return $.isNumeric(value);
    }, '');

    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('isnumeric', function (options) {
        options.rules['isnumeric'] = {};
        options.messages['isnumeric'] = options.message;
    });
```

not shown here, I have tested that the isNumeric method does get entered when a user types in the input or submits the form.

The issue is the submission of the form. The two events, InvalidHandler and SubmitHandler simply doesn't fire.

I have implemented it using the method on the Jquery Validation Site - which is passing in the handlers as a Javascript object to the `$("form").validate({ invalidHander: function(e, validator){ ... });` method - it didn't fire off

now I have this approach:

```
     $(document).on("click", "button[type='submit']", function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).data("customValidate") === true) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(e.target).parents("form");

            $(form).data("validator").settings.submitHandler = function (formhandler) {
                alert('submit');
                formhandler.submit();
            }; // <----

            $(form).data("validator").settings.invalidHandler = function (e, validator) {
                alert('error');
                for (var i = 0; i < validator.errorList.length; i++) {
                    var element = '#' + validator.errorList[i].element.name;
                    var error = validator.errorList[i].message;
                    if (!error || error === "undefined") {
                        error = "This field is required.";
                    }
                    $(element).prop('title', error);
                    $(element).data('placement', 'right');
                    $(element).data('toggle', 'tooltip').tooltip('show');
                }
            }; // <----

            $(form).validate();
        }
    });
```

Which is directly setting the invalid and valid handlers for the Jquery Unobtrusive Validation Engine in the form's data.

Neither approach works. I have worked on another MVC site with my team before where this approach worked, though I haven't implemented the unobtrusive validation - so the reason this doesn't work as I implemented above escapes me.

Any suggestions on what I might have missed?

Comment: Slightly irrelevant - before I tried these approaches (which makes sense to be correct), I have only checked the error list for entries. on the first time I submit the form, even though fields were erroneous, the error list was empty. immediately submitting the form a second time, it was populated and the tooltips in the code displayed

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix in my case- e.preventDefault had to be removed.

Comment: If you remove e.preventDefault you are simply allowing the defaultBehavior to occur of your code runs in your handler, how could this possibly solve your problem, validation will fire after you code?